# Diferencias entre clases de lectura de ficheros

Tags: java

tengo unas dudas respecto a las clases FileReader/bufferedReader y FileWritter/BufferedWritter, ya que no tengo muy claro en que momento conviene mas utilizar una o la otra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- FileReader es utilizado para leer archivos de caracteres, es decir
  archivos de [texto plano](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_texto) que contengan caracteres [ASCII](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

- BufferedReader También se puede usar para leer archivos de texto,
  pero sin embargo puede ser utilizado para leer otro tipo de contenido
  que no necesariamente provenga de un archivo de texto, además de que 
  BufferedReader soporta [UTF](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

- BufferedWriter también tendría las mismas características que
  BufferedReader sólo que se usa para escribir contenido en archivos u 
  otros lados.

- FileWriter tiene las mismas características que FileReader sólo que
  se usa para escribir texto en archivos.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar [la respuesta de FrEqDe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/70993/227), la principal diferencia es cómo funcionan estas clases internamente.

- `FileReader` y `FileWriter` sirven para leer/escribir **archivos de texto plano**. Las funcionalidades que ofrecen es leer el contenido de los archivos y almacenarlos en `char[]` (arreglo de caracteres) o en `CharBuffer` (un buffer de caracteres que internamente usa un arreglo de caracteres). Es decir, el trabajo con estas clases solamente requiere un nivel más bajo puesto que no interactúan con `String`.
- `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` sirven como wrappers (conocido en el mundo de patrones de diseño como [decorator](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o))) de otros `Reader`/`Writer` de texto y permiten leer/escribir todo un grupo de contenidos por ti. Por ejemplo, `BufferedReader` va a leer por adelantado contenido del `Reader` al que envuelve y lo almacenará en un buffer (usualmente un `char[]`) de modo que facilite y mejora el rendimiento de la lectura del contenido del `Reader` a futuro.

  Ojo que `BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` no se limitan a trabajar solo con `FileReader`/`FileWriter` respectivamente, también pueden combinarse con otras implementaciones como [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)/[`OutputStreamWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) para envolver cualquier tipo de stream de datos, lo cual permite leer/escribir sobre tramas de red (`DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream`) o al momento de leer la respuesta de un servicio consumido por HTTP p.e. al usar la librería Apache HttpComponent y conectarse a una url:

  ```
  CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");
  try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
      //leer la respuesta del servicio
      String linea = "";
      while ( (linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(linea);
      }
  }
  ```